# create detached child process in java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I'm trying to update a running java program and for that I'm executing a shell script to do the update .
this how a do lunch the script :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x " + spherDir + "/deploy.sh");
```

the problem is that inside the deploy.sh there is a command that kill the running instance before the script finished his execution.

My question is how to create a detached process that continue his execution even when the main programe (parent programm) stops !!

I'm on linux and I already tried `ProcessBuilder` without success.

here the java code :

```
File file = new File(spherDir +"/restore.sh");
boolean bool = file.createNewFile();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

try
{
    writer.write("#!/bin/sh\n\n");
    writer.write("service spher stop \n"); // stop the server chameleon
    writer.write("rm -rf " + appServerDir + " \n");
    writer.write("cp -Rap " + spherDir + "/currentdistrib/app-server  " + spherDir +"/app-server \n");
    writer.write("rm -rf " + spherDir + "/ui-server \n");
    writer.write("cp -Rap " + spherDir + "/currentdistrib/ui-server  " + spherDir + "/ui-server \n");
    writer.write("rm -rf " + spherDir + "/currentdistrib \n");
    writer.write("chmod +x " + spherDir + "/app-server/chameleon.sh \n"); /// Alaways do that to ensure that the script is runnable
    writer.write("sleep 5s \n"); /// Alaways do that to ensure that the script is runnable
    writer.write("touch README \n"); /// Alaways do that to ensure that the script is runnable
    writer.write("service spher start \n");

} catch(IOException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    writer.close();
}

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 755 " + spherDir + "/restore.sh");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", spherDir + "/restore.sh");
final Process process = pb.start();
```

Comment: Can you post your code, of your java program? and the script?

Comment: @BatScream: Why are either relevant?

Comment: If you add and ampersand & to the script launch?

Comment: @BatScream presumably because the OP wants to _restart_ the parent process. And whilst it is possible to upgrade modules etc using OSGi it is much simpler to simply replace the libraries in the classpath and restart.

Comment: @BatScream: Ah, I misread the OP's question.  I hadn't grasped that it's the script that's killing things!

Comment: @Dimitri: That's a shell construct, though.

Comment: After looking in the javadoc(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)), the exec already creates a new process when executing the command. I would suggest to check your script. Can you post the code of your script?

Comment: the exec is not working ?? any athor idea